# Weighted Average Loan to Value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, weighted-average

I was wondering how you can calculate the Weighted Average LTV in Excel. I calculated the LTV for every Loan, but I am stuck on finding the weighted average for it.

Comment: Usually one uses the sumproduct formula to calculate a weighted average. Your questions in not very specific, so please clarify if there is something more you need. https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel-tips/use-sumproduct-to-calculate-weighted-averages/1/

Answer (score 0):

Weighted average LTV is calculated using

```
SUMPRODUCT(LTVs,Loans) / SUM(Loans)
```

[image: formula for weighted average LTV (loan to value)]